# How can I remove administrator from a group?

Tags: linux, group

We know that modify the shadow files directly using vi isn't a good idea, and so vigr, vipw and visudo were developed to better perform this action. How can I remove a admin from a group? Is it possible to do this without editing gshadow directly?

```
[root@server230 ~]# gpasswd -A user1 -g linuxadm
[root@server230 ~]# !grep
grep linuxadm /etc/gshadow /etc/group
/etc/gshadow:linuxadm:!:user1:
/etc/group:linuxadm:x:6000:
[root@server230 ~]# gpasswd -d user1 -g linuxadm
Removing user user1 from group linuxadm
gpasswd: user 'user1' is not a member of 'linuxadm'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just find the answer:

```
[root@server230 ~]# gpasswd -A '' linuxadm
[root@server230 ~]# !grep
grep linuxadm /etc/gshadow /etc/group
/etc/gshadow:linuxadm:!::
/etc/group:linuxadm:x:6000:
```

Comment: You could also just do a `vim /etc/<file>` and remove the username from the line then save the file.

Comment: @thebtm I find that is possible to use vigr -s to edit shadow files.